# enumeration depending on section

Tags: biblatex, enumerate

How can I achieve that my enumeration is dependent on the section I am in?

For example in section 1:

```
begin{enumerate}
\item ....
```

and the enumeration would then be 1.1,1.2, etc.

And in section 2: the enumeration is then 2.1,2.2, etc.

Comment: `\renewcommand\theenumi{\thesection.\arabic{enumi}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go I hope this helps :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction :}
Here's a list :
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesection.\arabic*.]
\item Item number one 
\item Item number two 
\end{enumerate}
\section{Another introduction :}
Here's another list :
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesection.\arabic*.]
\item Item number one 
\item Item number two 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Keep in mind here `thesection` is the numbering of the section, which is in this case (article class) `1., 2., ...` in the book class things are different, `thesection` is thenumberofchapter.thenumberofsection to solve this you can redefine which is easy and here how it goes :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some introductions :}
\section{Introduction :}
Here's a list :
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesection.\arabic*.]
\item Item number one 
\item Item number two 
\end{enumerate}
\section{Another introduction :}
Here's another list :
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thesection.\arabic*.]
\item Item number one 
\item Item number two 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result :

[image]